# Can included C files be also ran directly?

Tags: c, include, program-entry-point

I'm wondering whether a C file can be both *included* in another script (through a header file), and also run independently (by having its own main function). That is, the C file can be included to provide its functions to another C script, but can also itself be directly ran to provide some alternate functionality.

For example, a python script can do this;

```
def functionsToBeImported():
    # code to be run by an importing script
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # code to be run by this script independently
    pass
```

This code can be imported (`import ABOVESCRIPT`) by another python file to give access to `functionsToBeImported`, or independently run (`python ABOVESCRIPT.py`) to execute the code within the `if` block.

I've attempted to do this in C via **myScript.c**:

```
#include "myScript.h"

void functionsToBeImported() {
}

int main (int narg, char* varg[]) {
}
```

**myScript.h**:

```
#ifndef MY_SCRIPT_H_
#define MY_SCRIPT_H_

void functionsToBeImported();

#endif // MY_SCRIPT_H_
```

but trying to include this in **anotherScript.c**:

```
#include "myScript.h"

int main (int narg, char* varg[]) {

    functionsToBeImported();
}
```

and trying to compile via

```
gcc -std=c99 -c myScript.c
gcc -std=c99 -c anotherScript.c
gcc -std=c99 -o anotherScript anotherScript.o myScript.o -lm
```

gives be a compilation error

```
duplicate symbol _main in:
    myScript.o
    anotherScript.o
```

How can I achieve this 'double-use' script?

Comment: One main() to rule them all.

Comment: I thought of a way to somewhat replicate what you are saying and edited my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot link both `anotherScript.o` and `myScript.o`, but you could do something like this:

```
#define main ignored_main
// Include myScript.c, not myScript.h
#include "myScript.c"
#undef main

int main (int narg, char* varg[]) {

    functionsToBeImported();
}
```

I have actually seen things like this in code very widely used in production, although I cannot recommend this style (but it is sometimes a tempting shortcut).

Another option is to include the `main` function only if a preprocessor macro is defined, like this (in `myScript.c`):

```
#include "myScript.h"

void functionsToBeImported() {
}

#ifdef USE_MAIN
int main (int narg, char* varg[]) {
}
#endif // USE_MAIN
```

This is similar in spirit to the Python approach.  But again, you will have to compile this file twice into separate object files.

Answer (score 1):

Note: C files are not scripts.

You cannot have two main functions, as C is a procedural language, meaning you must do one thing at a time (unless you are multithreading, in which case you would still only have one main function).

**HOWEVER,** there is something quite close to replicating what you want. What you can do is first, write the main method only in the first included file. In the main file, set the atexit() function from the C stdlib.h file (which calls another function at the end of main) to a main2() function (make sure that there is a prototype of each main#() function in the first header as well, and implement all of the functions eventually). Define a macro called MAIN_ONE in the function with the original main. In each consecutively included file, implement the next main and create a macro so that checks to see if the function was implemented can be made. However, the natural, and most efficient way to  make a program in C is to just have one main function.

Example:
    //In first included file
    #include  //Some IDEs automaticaly include this. This must be included since it is where the atexit() function resides

```
#define MAIN_ONE
void main2(); //For the moment, this is only a prototype.
void main3(); 
//etc. Until you have created the maximum number of main functions that you can have
int main() {
    //do something
    atexit(main2); // This will execute the function main1() once main returns
    //All "fake" mains must be void, because atexit() can only receive void functions
}

//In second included file
#if defined(MAIN_THREE) //start from the maximum number of main functions possible
    #define MAIN_THREE //The define is for preprocessor-checking purposes
    void main4() {
        atexit(main5);
    }
#elif defined(MAIN_TWO) //start from the maximum number of main functions possible
    #define MAIN_TWO
    void main3() {
        atexit(main5);
    }
//Keep repeating until you reach #ifdef(MAIN_ONE)
#endif

//At the bottom of the main C file
//This is done in order to make sure that all functions have actually been created and reside in memory so that an error does not occur
//(all unused functions are initialized with an empty function here)
#if defined(MAIN_THREE) //start from the maximum number of main functions possible
    //Do nothing because if MAIN_THREE is defined when main4(), the last main in my example has already been implemented.
    //Therefore, no more functions need to be created
#elif defined(MAIN_TWO) //start from the maximum number of main functions possible
    #define MAIN_TWO //Since more mains after main2 can be present, another macro for future checks needs to be defined
    void main3() {
    }
//Keep repeating until you reach #ifdef(MAIN_ONE)
#endif
```

Comment: I cannot understand the relevance of your first paragraph. Could you provide some example snippets for your proposal?

Comment: @Anti Earth I added an example